# QListView.indexAt in PyQt5 returning wrong index?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qlistview

I'm trying to pop up a context menu when a user right-clicks on an item in a QListView and a different context menu if the user right-clicks outside of any of the items (any of the whitespace).  What I'm finding is that the index I'm receiving when performing the indexAt command is not accurate, and I can't figure out why.

I initialize the QListView as its own class:

```
class RBKDataTypesTab(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.models = []
        grid = QGridLayout()
        self.list = QListView()
        self.list.clicked.connect(self.list_item_selected)
        grid.addWidget(self.list, 0, 0, -1, 8)
        self.table = QTableView()
        self.indexMenu = QMenu()
        self.indexMenu.addAction('Add DataType', self.addDataType)
        self.indexMenu.addAction('Remove DataType', self.removeDataType)
        self.nonIndexMenu = QMenu()
        self.nonIndexMenu.addAction('Add DataType', self.addDataType)
        grid.addWidget(self.table, 0, 2, -1, -1)
        self.setLayout(grid)
```

At this point, the list is empty.  I have other functions when a file is opened to set the model, which loads the data on the screen.

Here is my contextMenuEvent:

```
def contextMenuEvent(self, event):
    index = self.list.indexAt(event.pos())
    print(index.data())
    if(index.isValid()):
        event.accept()
        self.indexMenu.exec_(event.globalPos())
    else:
        event.accept()
        self.nonIndexMenu.exec_(event.globalPos())
```

Let's assume I have three generic items:

- item1
- item2
- item3

Thanks to the print statement, I can tell when I click the top 1/4 of item1 in the QListView, it is returning item1.  If I click in the bottom 3/4 of item1, however, it is returning item2.  Same logic for item2 and item3, only the bottom 3/4 of item3 returns None, hence returning the wrong context menu.

Can someone help me understand why this is happening?  I'm thinking it has something to do with event.pos(), but I don't know what.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The coordinates of the `event.pos()` are with respect to the widget that owns the `contextMenuEvent()` method, in your case it is with respect to the window but the `indexAt()` method expects coordinates with respect to the `viewport()` of the view(QListView) so You have to do a transformation using the `mapFromGlobal()` method:

```py
def contextMenuEvent(self, event):
    gp = event.globalPos()
    lp = self.list.viewport().mapFromGlobal(gp)
    index = self.list.indexAt(lp)
    if index.isValid():
        self.indexMenu.exec_(gp)
    else:
        self.nonIndexMenu.exec_(gp)
```

Comment: Thank you so much!!  After I posted this at 5:30am, I had a similar idea, involving a new class inherited from QListView and changing its contextMenuEvent, but your solution is far more concise!!  I like it!!