# Wrong directory being accessed upon right click for context menu

Tags: python, indexing, treeview, pyqt5, contextmenu

When I right click a file in tree view, context menu and it's underlying methods work.

However, when I right click on empty space and context menu opens, delete and archive methods apply on my working folder itself (i.e. where the test_gui.py file is stored).

I'm fine with the context menu popping up on empty space, I just don't want it to be able to do anything in that case.

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
import sys
import os
import send2trash
import shutil

class Ui_MainWindow(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.resize(800, 600)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)

        # Treeview model, path should contain files for test purpose
        path = r"C:\Test_gui"
        self.fileModel = QtWidgets.QFileSystemModel()
        self.fileModel.setReadOnly(False)

        # Treeview functionality
        self.treeView = QtWidgets.QTreeView(self.centralwidget)
        self.treeView.setModel(self.fileModel)
        self.treeView.setRootIndex(self.fileModel.setRootPath(path))
        self.treeView.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(190, 130, 541, 381))
        self.treeView.setContextMenuPolicy(QtCore.Qt.CustomContextMenu)
        self.treeView.customContextMenuRequested.connect(self.openMenu)

        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate


    def delete(self, index):
        """ Send the selected file to the recycle bin"""
        path = self.fileModel.fileInfo(index).absoluteFilePath()
        # When context menu is opened (right click) on a file, send2trash 
        # sends file to the bin. However, if context menu is open on empty 
        # space, delete method sends my working directory to the bin. 
        print(os.path.abspath(path))
        # send2trash.send2trash(os.path.abspath(path))


    def archive(self, index):
        """Move selected file to archive"""
        source = self.fileModel.fileInfo(index).absoluteFilePath()
        destination = r"C:\Test_gui_archive"
        # Same as above, but the archive method sends the working directory 
        # to archive.
        print(os.path.abspath(source))
        # shutil.move(os.path.abspath(source), os.path.abspath(destination))


    def openMenu(self, position):
        """Setup a context menu to open upon right click."""
        index = self.treeView.indexAt(position)
        menu = QtWidgets.QMenu(self)
        delete_action = menu.addAction("Send to trashbin")
        archive_action = menu.addAction("Move to archive")
        action = menu.exec_(self.treeView.viewport().mapToGlobal(position))
        if action == delete_action:
            self.delete(index)
        if action == archive_action:
            self.archive(index)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Tried to apply the logic from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59174609/qlistview-indexat-in-pyqt5-returning-wrong-index) thread, but was not successful. Advice would be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To verify that you are in the empty space you can use the index as it will be invalid.

According to this you can make several decisions:

- Disable the QActions:

  ```
  def openMenu(self, position):
      """Setup a context menu to open upon right click."""
      index = self.treeView.indexAt(position)
      menu = QtWidgets.QMenu(self)
      delete_action = menu.addAction("Send to trashbin")
      archive_action = menu.addAction("Move to archive")
      for action in (delete_action, archive_action):
          action.setEnabled(index.isValid())
      action = menu.exec_(self.treeView.viewport().mapToGlobal(position))
      if action == delete_action:
          self.delete(index)
      if action == archive_action:
          self.archive(index)
  ```
- Or not show the QMenu:

  ```
  def openMenu(self, position):
      """Setup a context menu to open upon right click."""
      index = self.treeView.indexAt(position)
      if not index.isValid():
          return
      menu = QtWidgets.QMenu(self)
      delete_action = menu.addAction("Send to trashbin")
      archive_action = menu.addAction("Move to archive")
      action = menu.exec_(self.treeView.viewport().mapToGlobal(position))
      if action == delete_action:
          self.delete(index)
      if action == archive_action:
          self.archive(index)
  ```

---

<sub>**Note:** I recommend you not to modify the code generated by Qt Designer but to implement a new class that inherits from the appropriate widget and use the initial class to fill it. For more information read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46545116/6622587) and [Using the Generated Code](https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Docs/PyQt5/designer.html#using-the-generated-code).</sub>

Comment: Wonderful, thank you for the elegant solutions and advice on using classes!